SQL FOR XML PATH Linebreak not generating "&#x0A;"
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    VALUES 
    (1001, 'LineA1' + CHAR(10) + 'LineA2')
    , (1002, 'LineB1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'LineB2')
) AS T(MyID, MyCol1)
FOR XML PATH('MyGrp1'), ROOT('MyROOT')

is generating
<MyROOT><MyGrp1><MyID>1001</MyID><MyCol1>LineA1
LineA2</MyCol1></MyGrp1><MyGrp1><MyID>1002</MyID><MyCol1>LineB1&#x0D;
LineB2</MyCol1></MyGrp1></MyROOT>

I want CHAR(10) to output as "&#x0A;" in the results, but it is being output (unchanged) as a linebreak
Am I misunderstanding something about how CHAR(10) should be handled?
Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)
EDIT: the data in columns needs to be preserved as-is. One issue we are facing is that "line break" within XML is getting converted to "<BR>" by something along the way. Clearly that shouldn't be happening, but I can't prevent it; if the XML contains "&#x0A;" instead then that get imported "unmodified". Maybe I will have to use just use REPLACE() to make that change within the XML to achieve that

Am I misunderstanding something about how CHAR(10) should be handled? probably. The universal newline is \n. Even Windows works fine with it nowadays. All applications that work with XML understand &#x0D; BUT what they do with it is up to them. Check How to add a newline (line break) in an XML file? and this question asking how to use CDATA to maintain text

A better question is why do you want \r\n ? Never mind \r which was only ever used in old MacOS versions

@Panagiotis Kanavos reason is to preserve the data in "text" fields as-is - export via XML and then import to a different location

Import how, where? Have you tried importing? Was there any problem? The very fact you have a standalone \r though means that something weird is going on with the data. Perhaps someone tried to "clean up" the text already and mangled newlines

In any case I already posted links to similar questions with answers. You can use REPLACE if you want to perform additional conversion if there's an actual problem.

@Panagiotis Kanavos Something in the transfer and import process (outside my control) is converting LineBreak to "<BR>", hence why I thought XML should "escape" CHAR(10), same as it does CHAR(13). I think REPLACE will be my best solution (just a bit worried in case that inadvertently replaces anything else in the data). I've clarified the original question

@Kristen good, let it. <br> is the newline in HTML. Which means your XML is actually treated and transferred as HTML. You should find out what's going on instead of making guesses that will be reversed by the rest of the process. If you know your data will be treated as HTML, make sure the data is encoded properly for HTML.

@Kristen, as Panagiotis told you, your input seems to be HTML. This looks very similar, but is not the same as XML. In fact, in most cases it will violate some XML rules (e.g. this <br> would have to be <br/>). There is XHTML, but this does not help you out. Shifting data to various text based containers will lead to multiple back and forth  conversions. You will have to analyse the flow of your data.

Something in the transfer I suspect the XML is displayed as HTML in some browser, or converted to HTML, and imported that way eg with a screen scraper. HTML doesn't respect extra whitespace, so preserving line feeds or even two consecutive spaces is a problem. Using FOR XML is a bad way to export to HTML. It would be a lot easier to read the data in a client application and generate an XHTML page using an HTML generator,  template engine or even ASP.NET. HTML generators take care of HTML-encoding the data and give you far better control of the output

Thanks. I fully understand that something downstream is inserting the '"<BR>" (the LF is retained so it is not a REPLACE), e.g. treating it as HTML, but - as is often the way - I can't do anything about that, I just need to work around it.
The only thing that has shown up as a problem (at the far end) is that inserted BREAK, other white space is preserved and so on.

you are mixing the presentation of the data, the actual data and the data within XML.

Presentation (what you get with .value()):
This is the real value. How you see this, is up to the application dealing with your data. This has nothing to do with XML or SQL-Server.
Data within:
If you simply cast your XML to strings you see all the <x> and you might see escaped characters. All Characters, which are either in conflict with the markup of XML itself (especially <, & and ;) or are unprintable are encoded. Many characters which are not printable must be escaped, as XML is a plain text container. This can vary. In your case, SQL-Server considers a new line as printable, therefore no escape code.
Actual Data:
A number or a date and many other data types are not strings behind the scene. Their binary value must be made human readable whenever you fetch it. Just imagine various date formats, cultural differences with . and , in numbers and so on. On the way into XML conversions take place. The reverse happens on the way out.

If I get this correctly you want to preserve existing data as is. No changes!
Try this and set "output to text":
SELECT t.stringInXml 
FROM (VALUES
       (CAST(N'<x>Hi, Kristen!</x>' AS XML))               --plain
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi, &#x4B;risten!</x>' AS XML))          --K as entity 
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,
Kristen!</x>' AS XML))                                    --typed new line (Enter-Key)   
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0A;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))          --0A entity
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0D;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))          --0D entity
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0D;&#x0A;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))    --both, expected order
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0A;&#x0D;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))    --both, other way round
) t(stringInXml);

You get
<x>Hi, Kristen!</x>
<x>Hi, Kristen!</x>
<x>Hi,
Kristen!</x>
<x>Hi,
Kristen!</x>
<x>Hi,
Kristen!</x>
<x>Hi,
Kristen!</x>
<x>Hi,

Kristen!</x>

The last one with the unexpected order uses both codes printed as a new line.
Now try this:
SELECT CAST(t.stringInXml.value('(x/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS varbinary(100))
FROM (VALUES
       (CAST(N'<x>Hi, Kristen!</x>' AS XML))               --plain
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi, &#x4B;risten!</x>' AS XML))          --K as entity 
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,
Kristen!</x>' AS XML))                                    --typed new line (Enter-Key)   
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0A;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))          --0A entity
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0D;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))          --0D entity
      ,(CAST(N'<x>Hi,&#x0D;&#x0A;Kristen!</x>' AS XML))    --both
) t(stringInXml);

You get these binary values (casted to varchar => 2 HEX per character, closest to the real data):
I will add some spaces to show the spots...
First block is "Hi,", then we see the varying part, last block is "Kristen!".
0x48692C 20    4B72697374656E21
0x48692C 20    4B72697374656E21
0x48692C 0A 09 4B72697374656E21
0x48692C 0A    4B72697374656E21
0x48692C 0D    4B72697374656E21
0x48692C 0D 0A 4B72697374656E21

The 20 is the blank, 0A and 0D are your line breaks.
The 09 appears because in my case the "typed new line" did not jump to the very first position in the line, there's an extra \tab. I just let it there if this occurs at your end to explain it. Easy to fix...
Conclusio:

If you want to keep the information consistent, I'd suggest to consolidate all line breaks to the modern standard. A line break is a line break. It is not important how this is done on binary level.
If you need to keep binary consistency you might cast your values to VARBINARY(MAX). The XML will store this as base64 and you can get back exactly what you filled in. But you won't be able to read it directly.

